# How to set layout and drawable on 7" two different tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, drawable, tablet

I have two 7 inch tablets. One tablet has resolution 800*480 and other has 1024*600. I'm facing the following problem  :

1) Both `tablet (1024*600)` and `tablet (800*480)` can run on `layout-sw600dp` and  so how can i make different folder to run my app in both resolution.

2) How can i make different`drawable folder` for both tablets .

Any one have idea for this issue

NOTE:Already read this article but am not getting any specific folders. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview